# How do I iterate over an Immutable Map returning selected name'd Maps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, immutable.js

I have an array of names that I want to find in an OrderedMap of Maps.

Example initialState json:

```
0:{id: 0, status: "success", name: "login", action: "", method: "", …}
1:{id: 1, status: "success", name: "default", action: "", method: "", …}
```

I know of `find()` but this only returns the map without its key pair, so it doesn't merge with the Key of my initialState.

I can get it to work if I manually create the key pair like this:

```
const selectedForm = (oldState, newState, name) => oldState.merge(
  OrderedMap({
    0: newState.find( o => o.get('name') === name)
  })
)
```

I've tried using `name.map(v,k)` to do this but every which way I doesn't seem work, either not returning at all or giving me a malformed Map.

Like this:

```
const selectedForms = (oldState, newState, name) => 
oldState.merge(
   name.map( (v,k) => newState.find( o => o.get('name') === 'login') 
)
```

Nothing seems to work though, is their some easier method I can use to do this?

Comment: I'm confused as to what your input and expected outputs are.  Be specific and give an example that has all the cases you seek to handle.

Comment: I also don't really understand what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you might want to look at [.findEntry()](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/findEntry) or possibly [.filter()](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/filter).

Comment: @SimonBaumgardt-Wellander that was exactly it! thank you! findEntry was what I was looking for, I knew there had to be something but for the life of me couldn't find it in the docs! thanks